# Image downloaded with NSURLConnection displays correctly on simulator, not at all on iPod

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, ipod-touch

I'm downloading an image (.jpg) from a webserver and then displaying it full screen in an UIImageView.  In the simulator the image is displayed correctly, but when I loaded the application on an iPod (iOS 4.3.2) I get a blank white page.  I get the NSData for the image back from the NSURLConnection and then set it in viewDidLoad with this code:

```
UIImage *map = [UIImage imageWithData:theData];
mapView.image = map;
```

My mapView is setup without an image in a UIView in Interface Builder.  I also have a toolbar that isn't showing on the device, like the UIImageView it shows up as expected on the simulator.  Has anyone seen similar behavior?

Comment: what is wrong with your image on the ipod?

Comment: As far as I know nothing, it's just not displaying.

Comment: How large is the image? Could it be an issue with memory occupation?

Comment: Image is only 20kb so I doubt it.

Comment: Please post the complete code you use to retrieve the image and assign to the `NSData`

Comment: I've saved the image from the NSData and then tried to load it directly into the UIImageView and it still isn't displayed.  Could I be missing a setting that would display it on the simulator but not on the actual device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was but I abandoned the Interface Builder and added the ImageView by hand and it now shows up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try with this code?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
       UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxx/xxxx.jpg"]]] retain];
       if (img != nil) {
            mapView.image = img;
            [img release];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

It is possibly not ok for you, but just for a try...

Comment: The image isn't nil and I don't want to block the main thread by using a synchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with ARC:

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
                  @"http://clasificados.eluniversal.com/imagenes/inmuebles/home/home_inmuebles.jpg"];

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
if (img != nil) {
    mapView.image = img;
    img = nil;
}
```